# How to use PhantomJS and Jasmine to test given URL?

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs

I've been following some [tuts](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine), they all seems to include some `js` file into the `src` folder and run it on a test Runner html.

I have a Web App running on `localhost:9292`, How can I test it? Say a really simple one, I want to test the title of the Web App is "My App", which not the title of the Test runner page.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to use phantomjs inside jasmine specs. You can use karma with jasmine to test localhost:9292 (set it in karma config file).

Here is a simple example how to test any web page with phantomjs. Hope it helps
https://github.com/mikach/phantomjs-test-runner